# Java greater common divisor with big double values

Tags: java, double

I'm trying to implement a gcd with doubles.

Here's my code:

```
public static double doubleGcd(double n1, double n2) {
    if (n2 != 0)
        return doubleGcd(n2, n1 % n2);
    else
        return n1;
}
```

It works well, until I test it with some big values.

As an example I've using:

- n1: Math.pow(10,25)
- n2: 14400

The GCD is 1600 but my code return 64.

I think the cause is the modulo operator and the fact the values are too big, but I can't figure out how to change the code to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using BigDecimal instead of Double type.

Here's my new Code:

```
public static BigDecimal Gcd(BigDecimal n1, BigDecimal n2) {
    if (n2.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0)) != 0)
        return Gcd(n2, n1.remainder(n2));
    else
        return n1;
}
```

Bigdecimal .remainder() is not the same as modulo operation, but in this case it works as well.

Docs:
[BigDecimal.remainder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)

Comment: Don't use `new BigDecimal(0)`. If anything, use `BigDecimal.ZERO`, however the `if` condition should be written as `if (n2.signum() != 0)`.